# (Writer) Is it professional to send links of articles I wrote on Reddit to recruiters?

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, unprofessional-behavior, portfolio

I've been publishing articles regularly on subreddits to gain traction and open discussions. I don't have a large digital following or a well-known blog so Reddit has been great to me.

One of the articles I've written recently gained huge traction. It was 94 percent upvoted, was viewed 40,000 times and users left more than 300 comments. I think this proves my ability to write an engaging piece so I should feature it in my portfolio.

The problem is that I don't know how recruiters might view it. My personal account on Reddit has nothing but published articles, and the article could've been featured anywhere. Reddit is just a great place for me to be heard, like Medium or any other blogging tool.

I'll be sending my portfolio to digital advertising agencies and by default they care about numbers and engagement, but Reddit is an unorthodox place to put your work.

Is it professionally acceptable to link the article on Reddit to my portfolio? I want to provide proof that my copy is engaging.

Comment: I think the issue here would be, if you could succeed on medium, or a platform more similar to the target platform, why did you choose reddit over that?

Comment: "they care about numbers and engagement, but Reddit is an unorthodox place to put your work" - I think you already answered your own question. I don't think we'll be able to tell you whether the pros will outweigh the cons here. If you do decide to include it, you might want to just link to your Reddit profile with a brief summary of achievements and let them come to their own conclusions (instead of linking to specific posts).

Comment: Anyone can make one thing that ends up being reasonably popular on the internet through sheer luck, and anyone in advertising worth working for will know that - you probably want to focus more on consistency and averages than just the popularity of that one post (unless maybe it spread far and wide to the point that it directly affects how a large portion of internet users interact).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends entirely on the kind of companies that you're looking to work for. If it's a marketing or media management company, then Reddit is a valuable platform. If it's for an editors position at a well reputed journal, paper etc. Then they may have differing opinions on Reddit as a platform for their content. It really comes down to their opinions on the various media platforms that are out there and which they value. It could also be argued that it could also come down to a cultural issue.

As to my own thoughts, I believe that Reddit, although perhaps not considered a "Mainstream" platform by some, is in fact an incredibly valuable social tool. There are hundreds of companies whose primary focus is to get things to go 'viral' for their clients. Reddit as much as any other platform allows the potential for a lot of exposure.

Are you 'Articles' hosted elsewhere and linked to in your Reddit posts? This would make a difference as it shows that you're able to route traffic to your content increasing exposure etc. The way that you disclose this to recruiters is the key, and the words you use to frame your achievements. If your articles are simply long posts on Reddit, then it might be argued that you're missing out on a valuable route of traffic that could be better put against increasing exposure of your own blog for example.

---

Links to some sites that discuss the validity of Reddit as a powerful tool for marketing, business, and traffic flow etc.

[So You Want To “Market On Reddit”](https://www.prweek.com/article/1397365/marketing-guide-reddit)

[The Marketing Guide to Reddit](https://www.prweek.com/article/1397365/marketing-guide-reddit)

[The Power of Reddit for Business and Marketing](http://grow.gardenmediagroup.com/bid/307001/The-Power-of-Reddit-for-Business-and-Marketing)

Answer (score 0):

To echo what @Dukeling said in a comment, you need to go for consistency rather than just the occasional hit. For example, I've written a blog article which ended with around 20k views and a high number of Reddit comments, but on r/programming. And I'm not pursuing a writing career. But whereas for me it was a fluke, for you it should be a steadier thing.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a company might find it unprofessional, but Reddit is being used more and more, so I might be wrong. Recently I've seen a company releasing information on future patches, and direct their customers to Reddit to get more information from the developers and discuss. My thought on this was, could you publish your article on a more "professional" site and link the Reddit as a means to discuss instead of having a dedicated comment section on the article. Of course link your Reddit post back to the published article as well.

Not sure if this would seem dishonest and cause a "which came first" situation, but it would give the company a professional place to first view your work and then you could direct them to the large following/discussion that your article has generated.

Answer (score 0):

Reddit is a mix of everything. The reaction you'll get will also be a mix of everything. A personal blog is a well-quantified medium, which has its set tone (personal, professional) and its target mood and audience.

Copy the article to your personal blog, and in there, link to the original Reddit post.

> Originally posted on Reddit, I decided to give some more thought to the subject since it was viewed by more than 40K people

You can include choice responses, which shows that people interacted with your content and provoked meaningful discussion - don't forget attribution.

Then edit your original Reddit post to link back to your blog

> *edit 20 Apr*: Also posted on my blog, Tawson's Fields. Come check it out!

---

There's no reason to do one or the other. You can test out content on Reddit and keep the best ones in a curated list on your blog. If you keep making good content, it'll boost your blog's rank which, needless to say, boosts your personal brand.